# Insert an event with a different date other than the current date on mysql with Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have Fullcalendar implemented which shows events from the mysql table (title+datetime) and also insert new events by clicking on a day within calendar.

The problem is that it only inserts events in the current day,even though the user has clicked on a future date or month. I want the user to be able to insert future events in the same way that I have now.

**Fullcalendar script which show events (events.php) and insert by clicking in the day (title) sending this info to "add_event.php"**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "http://localhost/test-fullcalendar/php/eventos.php",
        lang: "es",
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,

        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Evento a insertar:');
            if (title) {

                start = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                end = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'php/add_evento.php',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: {title: title, start: start, end: end},
                     success: function(json) {
                        alert("Evento insertado");
                        console.log("Enviando: ", title, start, end);
                     }
                 });
                 calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                 {
                     title: title,
                     start: start,
                     end: end,
                     allDay: allDay
                 },
                 true
                 );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that you override the selected date with a date that doesn't exist (`event.start`) and as such will default to now. And when you add the event to the calendar, it will use the overwritten values instead of the one passed to the `select` callback.

Before:

```
            start = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            end = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

             $.ajax({
                 url: 'php/add_evento.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {title: title, start: start, end: end},
                 success: function(json) {
                    alert("Evento insertado");
                    console.log("Enviando: ", title, start, end);
                 }
             });
```

After:

```
            start_ajax = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            end_ajax = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

             $.ajax({
                 url: 'php/add_evento.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {title: title, start: start_ajax, end: end_ajax},
                 success: function(json) {
                    alert("Evento insertado");
                    console.log("Enviando: ", title, start_ajax, end_ajax);
                 }
             });
```

Comment: I added ``event´´ before ``(start)´´ and ``(end)´´ because without ``event´´ it cant show correctly the hour format and it only shows 00:00:00 in console for example, clicking on 3march event: `the-title 2015-03-03 00:00:00 2015-03-04 00:00:00`. I read the doc of Fullcalendar and `HH:mm:ss` is the only way to have the hour format which i need to my mysql table (DATETIME column). Thanks for your response

Comment: In the `select` callback there is no`event` variable passed so what you did was trying to access a non existing variable and thus the conversion to DATETIME was done on current date instead of the actual calendar selected date. `event` variable is passed to other Fullcalendar callbacks but not to the `select`.

Comment: I understand what are you explaining but i dont see where is the solution to the problem. By adding `event` like a variable passed to `select` function like `select: function(start, end, event, allDay)` it only returns the same and not the date of the exactly event/title. Thanks

Comment: Read the docs http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/ . It says clear that `start` and `end` hold the selection times. Use those to send to the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current selected date with

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
```

it will return a moment.js date object